# Setting layer transparency with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, symbology, transparency-opacity

Is there a PyQGIS code to edit the transparency of rule based symbols?

[image]

Comment: You can change the opacity levels of your symbols with .setOpacity()

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#graduated-symbol-renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [@wanderzen's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442636/how-to-set-transparency-in-qgis-with-pyqgis#comment722667_442636) to this question you can use [`setOpacity()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbol.html#aa1f47455bcffabe11adab0980f40aaea) to change the transparency of a symbol.

Symbols themselves can be accessed from each of the rules (`QgsRuleBasedRenderer::Rule`) stored by the [`QgsRuleBasedRenderer`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedRenderer.html) as children of the invisible *root rule*.

An example to set all all rules to 75% opacity would be:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
root_rule = layer.renderer().rootRule()

for rule in root_rule.children():
    rule.symbol().setOpacity(0.75)
    
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: I don't manage to make your code work. I get this error: 
'QgsSingleSymbolRenderer' object has no attribute 'rootRule'

Comment: @zakros This question is about changing opacity of the individual symbols of a rule based renderer. If you are using a single symbol renderer you can just use `layer.setOpacity(0.75)`

Comment: Thanks for answering me. Yes but if I use setOpacity I can't change the opacity of only the selectedFeatures

Comment: I tried this:
`vlayer = iface.activeLayer()`

`vlayer.selectByExpression('"field_A"= \'category_FZ15\'', QgsVectorLayer.SetToSelection)`

`vlayer.selectedFeatures()[0].setOpacity(1)`
`
But I get this: 
`AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'setOpacity'`